# @Transactional annotation rollbackFor values does not working in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions

i test on the @Transactional rollback during a service layer method process.

below my code.

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
public RetryHistory failedOnCreateContainer() {
    final Container container = new Container();

    try {
        Container savedContainer = containerRepository.save(container);
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Force Error");
    } catch(UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        log.error("Error : {}", e.getMessage());
        return retryHistoryRepository.save(new RetryHistory(container.getName()));
    }
}
```

i forced an error. in doing so, i thought that data should not be stored in the container table. and data should be stored in retryHistory table.

but contrary to my expectation, the data was also stored in the container table.

can you tell me why?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but as per i thought if you have an idea regarding formal way to implementation of Hibernate you bit confirm that. You occupied Transaction object at start and on that transaction processing you get given error and suppose till that actual object is not available for process or you not allow to use same one. In short Transaction object not exist for db processing. It flush database object before that. It's good if you share error snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction is not rolled back because you are actually handling the exception within the function. So the function did not throw `UnsupportedOperationException`, it ends with returning `retryHistoryRepository.save`.

For it to rollback `containerRepository.save`, you need to move the try-catch outside of the function and let the function throw the exception, then spring data will rollback everything that was done within that function. You can also use [TransactionTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) instead of @Transactional if you want to keep the logic within this function.

Comment: as you said, i threw an exception and it was rollback.